# Swagger UI - Unknown Type: ınteger problem

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger, openapi, swashbuckle

I made a web app in asp.net core 3 and i added swagger ui. 
When i open swagger, it see `ı`nteger type not `i` char.  So it doesnt recognize int32 type suitable.
I have a viewmodel in backend.

```
public class ArticleAddViewModel
{
        public string ArticleTitle { get; set; }
        public string ArticleContent { get; set; }
        public int ArticleCategoryId { get; set; }
        public int ArticleUserId { get; set; }
        public string TagNames { get; set; }
}
```

```
 services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
 {
     c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo { Title = "My API", Version = "v1" });
 });
```

```
app.UseSwagger();
// Enable middleware to serve swagger-ui (HTML, JS, CSS, etc.),
// specifying the Swagger JSON endpoint.
app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
   c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "My API V1");
   c.RoutePrefix = string.Empty;
});
```

Why swagger doesnt recognize like integer type of my properties?

[image]

Comment: Can you post your `swagger.json` or at least the relevant portion, so we can see what was generated

Comment: @HelderSepulveda https://ghostbin.co/paste/ckoew it was generated "ı" character instead of "i". (ınteger) we have a dotless i character in Turkish alphabet.  [ ı => latin extended-a U+0131]

Comment: Strange that even compiles like that....

Comment: I think this problem is related to System.Text.Json APIS comes with dotnet core 3. Just a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downgraded `Swashbuckle.AspNetCore 5.3.1` to 5.0.0 and 
I added a new nuget package. `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson 3.1.3`

Then i wanted to use newtonsoftjson configs because with asp.net core 3 i guess json config settings changed to System.Text.Json.
so i added 
`services.AddSwaggerGenNewtonsoftSupport();` after `AddSwaggerGen()` method.

in configureservices method